# "No instance found" when using seq

Tags: alloy

I'm puzzled by the fact that Alloy reports `No instance found` for this model using `seq`:

```
one sig Const {
  T: seq (seq Int)
}

fact const_facts {
  Const.T = {
    0 -> {0->1 + 1->9} +
    1 -> {0->3 + 1->15}
  }
}

run {} for 20 but 6 Int, 8 seq
```

While the following model, where I simply replaced each `seq` with `Int ->`, has an instance as one would expect:

```
one sig Const {
  T: Int -> (Int -> Int)
}

fact const_facts {
  Const.T = {
    0 -> {0->1 + 1->9} +
    1 -> {0->3 + 1->15}
  }
}

run {} for 20 but 6 Int
```

It's especially confusing to me since https://alloytools.org/quickguide/seq.html seems to imply that `seq X` and `Int -> X` are the same thing type-wise.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The `Const.T` you create has an arity of 3 while a `seq` must be an arity of 2.

```
┌──────────┬──────┐
│this/Const│T     │
├──────────┼─┬─┬──┤
│Const⁰    │0│0│1 │
│          │ ├─┼──┤
│          │ │1│9 │
│          ├─┼─┼──┤
│          │1│0│3 │
│          │ ├─┼──┤
│          │ │1│15│
└──────────┴─┴─┴──┘
```

The predicates and functions for `seq` assume an arity of 2. I.e. a `seq` is not like an object, it is a convention for functions and predicates that take an arity 2 tupleset where the first column is an integer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Peter.

A colleague of mine also explained to me that `seq` imposes a number of constraints like 1. each index of the seq must map to at most one element, and 2. there are no gaps in the indices.

So it seems that using `seq` on the outside violates the first case: `0 -> {0->1 + 1->9}` would be expanded to `0 -> {0->1} + 0 -> {1->9}`. Same with other indices of the outer sequence.

So, I think what I want is `T: Int -> (Seq Int)` and to impose additional constraints manually.

By the way, this is all in the quest of modelling a 2d array. Is there a better way?

Comment: Well, Alloy sucks quite badly for numbers because it uses the SAT solvers that tend to blow up when many integers are used. In general, by advice of Daniel Jackson, one tries to avoid numeric problems. Quite often you can change the problem to a non-numeric problem. And if it is a numeric problem I think you're out of luck.